# Android app for continous camera monitor and email notification if red lamp detected

Tags: android, monitoring, camera

I want to use an old android device to camera monitor a red LED on a machine and email when the LED turns on.

Must have features:

1. Keep the camera on and monitor the camera image for a red led light (I can tape the android device camera to the LED so detecting light/dark conditions may be good enough)
2. When light is detected, automatically send an email

What I have already tried:

- There are many "light meter" type apps in the Play Store. I've tried some but none had both features 1 and 2.
- Searches for "red light detection" and similar terms give a lot of distracting hits on apps that use GPS and a database to detect road traffic red lights, which are no good for my use case.

Comment: I've initially thought about my list for [Video Surveillance & WebCams](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_webcams). But I'm not sure if any of them has e-mail functionality. At least, walking the list might be easier than evaluating search-results at Google Play; if you found a matching one, be welcome to answer your own question :)

Comment: Very handy list! I will research the apps. I've so far only found surveillance type apps that have notification on movement detection (not light change or color detection).

Comment: Those are the only ones I'm aware of as well. Still, I might have missed this as I hadn't such an idea in mind when building up the list (btw: many more lists there on a wide range of topics, you might have noticed ;)